# Google OAuth 2.0 returns invalid redirect_uri_mismatch when getting access_token even though code is retrieved successfully

Tags: google-api

I am getting this error regardless of what i post. I have validated that I am sending whats in the Developer console. I have even added https to the console and passed that in even though I am developing without it. I cannot for the life of me figure out whats missing...

code=4%2FtZZH7puwSXu0K6HS8TmkLiO9DxTQgJYM7Yo7sxgF7eY.wh2HsuyeNREUPm8kb2vw2M2hgewOlQI
redirect_uri=http%3A%2F%2F{urlhere}%2FCamYam%2FPicasa%2FGetUserGalleries
client_id=577137571667-6k1mpbmtjo1aod88s7hjgij19lsmh8rv.apps.googleusercontent.com
client_secret=****************
grant_type=authorization_code

This is being POSTed to https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/token...

I get the code successfully with the request_uri working there. Not sure whats left.. and the documentation is severely lacking here.

For the record, I am following the Oauth playground almost identically...

Any help would be greatly appreciated

-- Edit

## -Im trying to call the Picasa API

## -Im POSTing using C# but also testing with Fiddler

## -I've the posted payload in the message above

## - I have successfully received a Code and am trying to exchange it for a token

Comment: I don't think anyone can help with out your code, programming language, api you are trying to access... basically more info..  But check port

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently, you need to pass the Url that the code was posted to as the redirect Uri.

ie, if you have a callback url that youre clients are being redirected to, thats the one you need as the redirect_url, not the one you want to go to